# XPath and min function not recognized in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

```
<td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//vrednostDelnice)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//vrednostDelnice)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice, '#.###,00 €', 'euro')"/>
                                    </td>
```

but I get

```
This document had an invalid XSLT stylesheet. Error message from the XSLT engine:
Error: XPath expression compilation failed: min(//vrednostDelnice)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice
Details: compilation error (characters 1-22, "min(//vrednostDelnice)"): unknown function called: 'min'
```

Why min is not recognized. Min s valid function: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_min.html

EDIT:

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="odlocitvenProblem.xsl"?>
<delnice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="odlocitvenProblem.xsd">
```

whole xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="kolicnik" select="'1000'"/>
    <xsl:key name="id" match="delnica" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <title>Delnice - seznam alternativ</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {font: normal 12px/1.6em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #2a3845;margin: 0;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px; background: #FFFFFF; width: 100%; }
                    table { margin: 0;padding  0; border: 1px solid #efece7; margin: 0 auto; font : normal 12px/1.6em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #2a3845; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
                    td { border: 1px solid #efece7; padding: 2px; }
                    th { border: 1px solid #efece7; padding: 2px; }
                    td.num { text-align: right;}
                    td.green { text-align: right; color: green;}
                    td.red { text-align: right; color: red;}
                    h1 { color: #7a2e40;margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;padding-bottom: 10px;font: normal 17px Georgia, serif;border-bottom: 1px solid #efece7;}
                    #wrapper {margin: 0 auto;border-left: 1px solid #f0e9eb;border-right: 1px solid #f0e9eb;}
                    #header {margin: 0 0px; background: #7a2e40;color: #f6dde3; height: 30px;}
                    #main-content { margin: 0 auto; float: left; padding-top: 30px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 10px;}
                    #footer {background: #f7f7f7; border-top: 1px solid #f0e9eb; border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9eb; clear: both; height: 30px; }
                    tr.footer { font-size: 10px; vertical-align: top;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="header">&#160;</div>
                    <div id="main-content">
                        <h1>Delnice - seznam alternativ</h1>
                        <br/>
                        <table cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2"></th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Naziv</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Kratica</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Vrednost delnice<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='vrednostDelnice']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th colspan="3">Sprememba tečaja</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Vrednost dividende<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='vrednostDividende']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Dividendni donos<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='dividendniDonos']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Promet<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='promet']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Tržna kapitalizacija<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='trznaKapitalizacija']/@utez"/>) *
                                </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Število delnic</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Čisti dobiček<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='cistiDobicek']/@utez"/>) *
                                </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Finančna sredstva<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='financnaSredstva']/@utez"/>) *
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Letna<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjeLeto']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th>Mesečna<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjiMesec']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                                <th>Dnevna<br/>
(<xsl:value-of select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjiDan']/@utez"/>)
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/delnice/*">
                                <xsl:sort select="nazivDruzbe"/>
                                <xsl:call-template name="alternative">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <tr class="footer">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='vrednostDelnice']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjeLeto']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjiMesec']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='zadnjiDan']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='vrednostDividende']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='dividendniDonos']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='promet']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='trznaKapitalizacija']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja div number($kolicnik)" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja div 1000" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='cistiDobicek']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja div number($kolicnik)" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja div 1000" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:for-each select="document('uteziParametrov.xml')/uteziDelnic/parameter[@naziv='financnaSredstva']/zalogaVrednosti">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@ocena"/>:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="spMeja div number($kolicnik)" /> - <xsl:value-of select="zgMeja div 1000" />
                                    <br/>
                                </xsl:for-each></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <span style="font-size: 80%;">* v <xsl:value-of select="$kolicnik"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer">&#160;</div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="alternative">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$node/nazivDruzbe"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="kratica"/>
                </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="fn:min(//vrednostDelnice)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//vrednostDelnice)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDelnice, '#.###,00 €', 'euro')"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//zadnjeLeto)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjeLeto">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//zadnjeLeto)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjeLeto">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjeLeto"/>%</td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//zadnjiMesec)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiMesec">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//zadnjiMesec)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiMesec">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiMesec"/>%</td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//zadnjiDan)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiDan">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//zadnjiDan)=trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiDan">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/spremembaTecaja/zadnjiDan"/>%</td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//vrednostDividende)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDividende">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//vrednostDividende)=trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDividende">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/vrednostDividende"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//dividendniDonos)=trgovalniPodatki/dividendniDonos">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//dividendniDonos)=trgovalniPodatki/dividendniDonos">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/dividendniDonos"/>%</td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//promet)=trgovalniPodatki/promet">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//promet)=trgovalniPodatki/promet">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="trgovalniPodatki/promet"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//trznaKapitalizacija)=trgovalniPodatki/trznaKapitalizacija">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//trznaKapitalizacija)=trgovalniPodatki/trznaKapitalizacija">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(trgovalniPodatki/trznaKapitalizacija div number($kolicnik), '###.###.###', 'euro')"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="financniPodatki/steviloDelnic"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//cistiDobicek)=financniPodatki/cistiDobicek">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//cistiDobicek)=financniPodatki/cistiDobicek">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="financniPodatki/cistiDobicek div number($kolicnik)"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="num">
                                        <xsl:if test="min(//financnaSredstva)=financniPodatki/financnaSredstva">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">red</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="max(//financnaSredstva)=financniPodatki/financnaSredstva">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">green</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="financniPodatki/financnaSredstva div number($kolicnik)"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What version of XSLT do **you** think you are using? What version of XSLT does **your XSLT processor** think you are using?

Comment: try fn:min as you are using an extension function

Comment: It is the same: Details: compilation error (characters 1-25, "fn:min(//vrednostDelnice)"): unknown function called: '{ http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions, min }'

Comment: fn:min should work fine. Can you post an example input document and a bit more of the stylesheet so we can check it ourselves? It might be a parser issue. What tool/library are you using? Maybe it requires some configuration.

Comment: i paste whole xsl code. I am using altoca xml spy and notepad++ dor xml. I am looking it with opera, where I can see errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `min` function is part of XSLT and XPath 2.0 and that way is supported by XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9, AltovaXML or XmlPrime. Inside the browser there is no support for XSLT 2.0 unless you use [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/download.xml). So the error you get simply means that you are trying to run XSLT 2.0 code with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Thank you for answer. And what can I do. I already have <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Comment: You need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor, not an XSLT 1.0 processor. I mentioned some XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9 http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ or like AltovaXML http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html. So install and use one of them if you want to use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that your stylesheet is a version 2.0 stylesheet isn't going to help if the XSLT processor you invoke only understands XSLT 1.0. I don't recognize the error messages you are getting, and there are no other clues in your post as to which XSLT processor you are using, but it does appear to be an XSLT 1.0 processor. Tell us how you are running the transform, e.g. from the command line, from the browser, or from an application in some programming language.