# how to use xsl 2.0 functions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have xml file with sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet version="2.0" type="text/xml" href="xml_stylesheet.xsl" ?>
<root>
    <values>
        <item value="2" />
        <item value="7" />
        <item value="10" />
        <item value="55" />
        <item value="1" />
        <item value="73" />
        <item value="45" />
        <item value="41" />
    </values>
</root>
```

and xsl template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <html>
            <body>
                <div>
                     The minimum of values is <strong><xsl:value-of select="fn:min(//item/@value)" /></strong>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**How can i use min function? when i try to open .xml file in firefox (and other browsers) , it display error message. Why? what is wrong?**

Comment: You told us that it displays an error message, but didn't bother to tell us what the message said?

Comment: It don't display concrete message, it simply say that function not found.

Comment: The error message may not be very "concrete", but it's far better than nothing. The fact that the XSLT processor is looking for a function that's missing, as opposed to having a syntax error, or passing an illegal argument to a function, or any of a huge number of other possible errors, tells us a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox, and other browsers in general, do not support XSLT 2.0. You'll have to use XSLT 1.0 and find an alternative for min(), which is from XPath 2.0.

See also: [XPath and min function not recognized in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683165/xpath-and-min-function-not-recognized-in-xslt)

Answer (score 2):

The native XSLT processors in the browsers are all XSLT 1.0. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 in the browser, you could look at Saxon-CE.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the JavaScript implementations of XSLT 2.0:

- [Frameless](http://frameless.io/xslt/)
- [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)

**References**

- [XSLT 2.0 as a web scripting language](http://programming.oreilly.com/2013/08/using-xslt-2-0-as-a-web-scripting-language.html)
- [XSLT Fiddle](http://fiddle.frameless.io/)
- [XSLT 2.0 Quick Reference (pdf)](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/xslt2.pdf)